# modprobe on Centos 7.3 returns multiple and/or strange results

Tags: centos, modprobe

Can someone please tell me why the following command

```
modprobe -n -v dccp_ipv4
```

returns two results ?

```
install /bin/true
install /bin/true
```

And why does

```
modprobe -n -v dccp_ipv6
```

returns three ?

```
install /bin/true
install /bin/true
install /bin/true
```

I'm on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core), and in /etc/modprobe.d
I have a number of files, among which a file with recommendations from CIS. This file contains (among others) :

```
install dccp_ipv4 /bin/true
install dccp_ipv6 /bin/true
```

Above two are the only occurences in the files in /etc/modprobe.d

Furthermore, a

```
modprobe -n -v udf
```

returns two lines as well :

```
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-514.21.2.el7.x86_64/kernel/lib/crc-itu-t.ko
install /bin/true
```

The content of the CIS file in /etc/modprobe.d is:

```
install udf /bin/true
```

So, why the insmod line ?

I'm asking this because a vulnerability scanner expects only one line of output (in this case install  /bin/true)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple results as there are multiple dependances:
`modinfo -F depends <module_name>`
will list the dependancies for that module.

eg:

```
$ modprobe -n -v dccp_ipv6                                  
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64/kernel/net/dccp/dccp.ko            
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64/kernel/net/dccp/dccp_ipv4.ko    
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64/kernel/net/dccp/dccp_ipv6.ko
```

> So, why the insmod line ?

The `udf` module depends on `udf` and `crc-itu-t` and the `crc-itu-t` is enabled for loading, hence the `insmod` line.

The `install /bin/true` indicates that the module is disabled - which is what  your scanner is looking for.

For me this behaviour is the same on CentOS 6.8 and 7.1.

Comment: Thanks. That explains a lot. I believe the scanner must be using the wrong regexp to test, because, even though the line install /bin/true is present, it also sees the other line(s) and then fails.....